# how to get first item from a group and prepare Data class object

Tags: c#

I have list of packets where I am doing ordering and group based on `DateAndTime` of `Result` and `Name` of `Packet`. and also selecting only `First` item.

```
 var packets = new List<Packet>
        {
            new Packet { Name = "P1", Result = new Result { Name = "N1", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 30, 50) }},
            new Packet { Name = "P1", Result = new Result { Name = "N2", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 31, 50) }},
            new Packet { Name = "P2", Result = new Result { Name = "N1", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 32, 50) }},
            new Packet { Name = "P1", Result = new Result { Name = "N2", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 33, 50) }},
            new Packet { Name = "P2", Result = new Result { Name = "N2", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 34, 50) }},
            new Packet { Name = "P1", Result = new Result { Name = "N1", DateAndTime = new DateTime(2020, 05, 11, 10, 35, 50) }}
        };

        var resultData = packets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Result.DateAndTime).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.First());
```

Supporting Classes,

```
public class Packet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to prepare `Data` object from above `resultData`,

```
public class Data
{
    public string PacketName { get; set; }
    public DateTime PacketTime { get; set; }
}


var data=new Data
   {
     PacketName = resultData.???

    }
```

How to do this? Also `OrderByDescending` when to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Data> datas = resultData.Select(x => new Data (){ PacketName = x.Name, PacketTime = x.Result.DateAndTime }).ToList();
```

Or

```
List<Data> datas = packets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Result.DateAndTime)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.Name) 
                          .Select(x => new Data() { PacketName = x.First().Name, PacketTime = x.First().Result.DateAndTime })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for one line query, but we have 2 times select and 2 time tolist. Can we minimize

Comment: You're welcome. I have edited my answer as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you want first item from each group , you will need to iterate through resultData and then populate list of data.

```
List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();


            foreach (var item in resultData)
            {
                var data = new Data
                {
                    PacketName = item.Name,
                    PacketTime = item.Result.DateAndTime

                };
            }
```

OR

If you want  only first item from result data :

```
            var data = new Data
            {
                PacketName = resultData.First().Name,
                PacketTime = resultData.First().Result.DateAndTime
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
            var resultData = packets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Result.DateAndTime).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, DateAndTime = x.Max(x => x.Result.DateAndTime) }).First();

            var data = new Data
            {
                PacketName = resultData.Name,
                PacketTime = resultData.DateAndTime

            };
```

Comment: Thanks @Kebek, this is only giving one group "P1"

Comment: yes it is, you declared your `data` as `var data=new Data`, which is only one object, if you wanted a one value per group this assigment was wrong :P

Answer (score -1):

i need to write this as an answer otherwise i cannot post pictures.

this is what your object currently looks like:

[image]

i am not getting what you are asking for? can you clarify?